# CSS: Background of top element hiding child element overflow

Tags: html, css

I currently need to do this in CSS:

[image]

This is a vertical menu so the yellow "div" count is not fixed, could be 5 like it could be 7.

For now, I have a div with this CSS applied:

```
#main-menu {
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 50px;
}
```

That contains the yellow div (nothing special). Then I added a "before" pseudo-element like this:

```
#main-menu::before {
    height:624px;
    width:250px;
    background-image: url("../img/SSC_fondgris_96_Background.png");
    content: " ";
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
}
```

The image used is just the curve with a transparent background on the left and the grey on the right. This results in the the image above. The issue is that I'd like to have an hover effect on the yellow div's but I can't get that because the "before" element is on top of them (which is wanted in order to allow the curve to hide the overflow of yellow items) and therefore, the "hover" effect is not applied for the yellow divs.

I guess that it's because the hover is done on the "before" pseudo element and that's exacly my issue. So the question is: is it possible to have an image hidding the overflow of child elements but allowing these children to have a hover effect? Bascailly, a z-index for hover effect:-D

The goal here would also be to avoid using JavaScript to do such things...

Comment: Have you tried using an SVG image for this?

Comment: Not really, no. I didn't know this could solve the issue. What do I have to do ? Just convert the PNG in SVG and that's it?

Comment: Wow... Clear and precise. Thanks a lot

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work for IE9/IE10...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `pointer-events:none` on the pseudo-element

From [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

> The CSS property pointer-events allows authors to control under what circumstances (if any) a particular graphic element can become the target of mouse events. When this property is unspecified, the same characteristics of the visiblePainted value apply to SVG content.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
}
ul::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  pointer-events: none;
}
li {
  padding: 25px 0;
  background: #000;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
li:hover {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is brilliant. I have never encountered `pointer-events: none;` before. Off to investigate: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to "click through" the pseudo element by negating the pointer events on the element:

```
#main-menu::before {
    height:624px;
    width:250px;
    background-image: url("../img/SSC_fondgris_96_Background.png");
    content: " ";
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    /* Add the below */
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

... let me know how that works for you.

I need to add that browser support is a little dodge though - only IE11 ... [caniuse - pointer-events](http://caniuse.com/#search=pointer-events)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the effect you want by introducing a third, transparent element which you position over the top of the transparent/grey image.

If your third, transparent element is exactly congruent with the yellow div (two layers below), then you can apply `:hover` effects to the uppermost, transparent element and it will *look like* the bottom-most element is responding to the hover.

Comment: Woul you have an example because I didn't really get that... Note that I also have a "::after" pseudo element used to continue the border until the bottom of the page. Not also that it has to be working with IE9.

Comment: I can build on your example if you can provide more of your code in your question above - including the HTML markup. Thanks. (Yes, it will work with IE7 upwards...)

Comment: Thanks but the answer of "Paulie_D" was the correct one.

Comment: And how would you click the actual links in the bottom layer?

Comment: Normally. The pointer-event just deactivate effect on the parent, so the children becomes available.